# 'System.Exception' thrown in new Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: c#, xaml, exception, xamarin.forms

I've installed a fresh copy of Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition on Windows 10 Pro Fall Creators Update recently, and I'm unable to properly create a new **ContentPage** on **Xamarin.Forms** (see screenshots 1-3). At my first attempt of creating a new **ContentPage** in a new **Xamarin.Forms** project, I encountered the errors seen on screenshot 1 and 2.

Next, an automated error log was generated (as attached). If I don't create any new items and run as-is, I can successfully launch the app on my Android emulator with no issues.

> Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown

[image: Screenshot 1 - Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown]

```
The project system has encountered an error.

Did not find new element in the hierarchy for item "Page2.xaml". The
item would have been added with type "Page". The project item
schema service knows about this item type. The item does exist
in the project file.

A diagnostic log has been written to the following location: "C:\..." (see below link)
```

[Automatically generated error log file - txt](https://nofile.io/f/wkAKHodW7Ob/VsProjectFault_abb5672e-0616-40de-aa95-132eea5196b3.failure.txt)

[image: Screenshot 2 - Project system encountered an error; did not find new element in the hierarchy for item "Page2.xaml"...]

The issues arise when I create a new **ContentPage**. The code-behind **.cs** file and **.xaml** file will not be immediately visible in the Solution Explorer. I need to manually click the **Show All Files** button to show the newly created files (as seen in screenshot 3). However, I couldn't include them into project despite multiple tries.

[image: Screenshot 3 - Newly created xaml and cs files (Page1, Page2) not immediately visible and cannot be included into project]

When I open a .xaml file (in this case Page2.xaml), errors mentioning missing references and assemblies are visible (see screenshot 4 below).

[image: Screenshot 4 - in editor while editing xaml files - The type 'ContentPage' was not found...]

I've done the following thus far:

- Removed mobile app development (Xamarin) in the Visual Studio
  installer
- Reinstalled Xamarin by including (checking) the mobile app
  development (Xamarin) in the Visual Studio installer

Are there any known solutions to this issue? Any assistance is kindly appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE (Feb 27):** Attempted recommendation by Paul-Jan but the issues still persist. However, the newly created **Page1.xaml** was properly included and recognized by Solution Explorer (as shown below).
[image: Newly created ContentPage is properly recognized]

Comment: You have taken effort to assemble your question, admittedly, but please don't add code and error messages as images, but as text. This will render the quetion much mor searchable and is way better to read and understand.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Paul! I've added the error code texts for screenshot 1 and 2. However, I've retained the screenshot links for anyone who's interested to know in full.

Comment: for missing references please delete pages manually if  you have deleted that pages.and then clean and rebuild.

Comment: are you new to xamarin? may i know how you are adding new xamal page in project?

Comment: I used Xamarin before, and I've come back recently to refresh my memory. Done deleting, cleaning, and building but there were no favorable results. I added a new ContentPage using Add > New Item from Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen with fresh VS2017 Professional installs where Universal Windows Platform (UWP) support was not added during install. Of course you might have no desire at all to develop for UWP, but apparently there are bits and pieces of the Xamarin Forms toolchain missing when you don't install it.

Running the Visual Studio Installer again, adding UWP support, helps.

[image: UWP Support checkbox in VS2017]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've installed UWP development, but the problem still persists. I tried removed mobile app development, UWP development, and reinstalled both, but the issues still persist.